# Azure AD B2C - Will I have a problem with CORS?

Tags: jwt, cross-domain, azure-ad-b2c

Im planning to adopt AD B2C. The idea is:

1. User access [www.mySubsidiary.com/login](http://www.mySubsidiary.com/login)
2. User is redirected to b2clogin.onmicrosoft.com/blablalba
3. After entering correct user+password and MFA user is redirected back to [www.mySubsidiary.com/login_landing_page](http://www.mySubsidiary.com/login_landing_page) with a cookie
4. Web app call APIs located at api.myHoldingCompany.com using the JWT present on the cookie

Due to the multiple DNSs present, I can't easily test this myself, so im running a desk test...

Anyone foresees any problem?

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not a problem with Azure AD B2C. Token retrieval for SPA relies on [non-CORS requests.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#what_requests_use_cors)